# WordPress home page not appearing

Tags: wordpress, installation, migration

I have just installed a WordPress site on GoDaddy but unfortunately the home page of the site does not appear - just stays in waiting mode with the progress wheel spinning.

But if I go down a level to `http://example.com/about-us`, the site appears as required but going back to just `http://example.com/` does not show anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the home page is set to look up data from a location that is unavailable? Try looking up the source of the home page and see if it is trying to resolve a non-existent page. In addition you might like to use the [W3C Validatior](http://validator.w3.org/) to check for errors before proceeding. You error otherwise seems quite vague.